# is there a way to group by using values in a range in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a little challenge coming up with a query. Here's the problem

I have a table of REF_NUMs and Amount. I want to group by using certain amount range and have the count of REF_NUMs in the different ranges. Below is a sample of my table.

```
REF_NUM TRAN_AMT
1612     2500
1613     51800000
1614     2170000
1615     100
1616     2442876.5
1617     25000
1618     250
1619     7000
1610     51500
1621     15000
1622     20
```

I want to group the REF_NUM with amount in the range <=5000, between 5001 and 50000 and >=500001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the counts, then you don't even need to group, you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
with  -- For testing only; remove and use actual table name in SELECT statement
  your_table (ref_num, tran_amt) as (
    select 1612,     2500   from dual union all
    select 1613, 51800000   from dual union all
    select 1614,  2170000   from dual union all
    select 1615,      100   from dual union all
    select 1616,  2442876.5 from dual union all
    select 1617,    25000   from dual union all
    select 1618,      250   from dual union all
    select 1619,     7000   from dual union all
    select 1610,    51500   from dual union all
    select 1621,    15000   from dual union all
    select 1622,       20   from dual
  )
select count (case when tran_amt <=  5000 then 1 end) as amt_to_5000,
       count (case when tran_amt >   5000 
                    and tran_amt <= 50000 then 1 end) as amt_from_5000_to_50000,
       count (case when tran_amt >  50000 then 1 end) as amt_over_50000
from   your_table
;

AMT_TO_5000 AMT_FROM_5000_TO_50000 AMT_OVER_50000
----------- ---------------------- --------------
          4                      3              4
```

Note how I use non-strict and strict inequalities, not `between`. With `between`, you would miss amounts like 5000.83 - they would not be counted anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mathguy. This worked for me and i got the desired output. Do you know how i can multiply the output of each column by a constant and return that in a row below.